# Why removing outliers with Z-Score still leaves out some values as outliers?

Tags: python, outliers

I am new to Ml. I am removing outliers with z-scores with the code given below. The problem I am facing is that when I remove outliers, it still leaves some values as outliers. Can anyone explain why is this so? Isn't Z-score a reliable method to remove all the outliers from the data?

I am calculating the z-score second time to know if there are any data points still left.

```
for feature in numerical_features:

   data = pd.DataFrame(housing[feature], columns=[feature])
   data = data.copy()
   z_scores = np.abs(stats.zscore(data[feature]))

   print("Before z score on ", feature, " ====> ", data[z_scores > 3].shape)
   data[z_scores > 3] = data[feature].median()

   z_scores = np.abs(stats.zscore(data[feature]))
   print("After z score on ", feature, " ===> ", data[z_scores > 3].shape)
   housing[feature] = data[feature]
   print()
```

Before z-score is the first time I apply z-score and tells me how many values will be impact when I replace with median.
After means, how many values are still left as outliers?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6kn2.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z-score tells you how many standard deviations away from the mean a certain point is. Using |z-score| > 3 is a very common way to identify outliers. What you are missing, is that when you remove/replace outliers, the standard deviation of your new distribution is different than it used to be, thus the z-scores of all remaining points are slightly different. In many cases, the change is negligible; however, there are some cases where the change in z-score is more pronounced.

Depending on your application, you may wish to run the z-score filter a couple times until you get a stable distribution. Also, depending on your application, you may consider dropping outlier data instead of replacing them with the median. Hopefully you know why you chose to replace and the caveats associated with that choice.

Comment: Thanks, Davis. If I keep iterating over this code multiple times, I may end up smoothing out the important information in the data... in the effort to reach a normal distribution, which can be better handled with binning techniques rather than smoothing out the information with a median. I find removing outliers pointless when they can help the model in learning.

Comment: The point is to know that threshold or a way to estimate that threshold when replacing the data points with median/mean results in smoothing out important information. What do you think?

Comment: And can you tell in what cases would you consider replacing outliers with median?

Comment: I don't follow all of what you are saying. To effectively remove/replace outliers, you only need to iterate once or twice. In manufacturing for example, outliers are removed once, then control limits (typically 3 standard deviations) are determined, and then any new outliers are flagged as bad parts. Since I don't know your specific application, I can't say if it makes sense to remove or replace. If you are doing any sort of statistics or learning, I would think replacing with the mean will skew your results by quite a bit.